# Error message position in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to put custom error messages for a login and registration forms.

So far I have the form to check if there's an email already registered, if it is, it will return

```
Response.Write("There's already someone with that email")
```

But the problem with this is that the message will only appear on the top of the website.

Is there a way I could display these error messages somewhere else?

I know that in the model I could just put

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Something here")]
```

And then just put in the view somewhere

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a =>a.Email)
```

and it will display the error there.

The code that I have for now is this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Registration signingUp)
    {


        var db = new ShareRideDBEntities();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //find if email is already signed up
            var FindEmail = db.tblProfiles.FirstOrDefault(e => e.PROF_Email == signingUp.Email);
            //if email is not found up do this
            if (FindEmail == null)
            {
                var Data = db.tblProfiles.Create();
                Data.PROF_Password = signingUp.Password;
                Data.PROF_Email = signingUp.Email;
                db.tblProfiles.Add(Data);

                int Saved = db.SaveChanges();

                if (Saved != 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("Registration Successful.");
                }

                else
                {
                    Response.Write("There was an error.");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("There's already an user with that email.");
                return View();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Fill all the fields to continue.");
        }

return View();
```

Now if I do this with an existing email it will return "There's already an user with that email." but it will be display on the top of the website.

How can I make this error message be displayed somewhere else?

I heard something with @Html.Raw() but I'm confused on how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `this.ModelState.AddModelError` method you can add any custom error message you want. If you specify property name as a key - it will be displayed by corresponding `ValidationMessageFor`. So in controller instead of writing to response directly do this:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "There's already an user with that email.");
return View();
```

And in view this line which you already have:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a =>a.Email)
```

will display this messagea at whatever part of the page you place it (presumably near the field for email).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, very simple too, thank you!